# Refreshing list view when selecting the fragments tab

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments

EDIT: I have browsed the many questions related to this for the last few hours and none seem to apply to the code i have; please don't mark as duplicate.

What is happening is in one tab, im adding items to the listview that is viewed in a separate tab, but i want to be able to update the listview with items added while within the app, without having to exit then reenter to get the list to update.

Here is my code for both the fragment Java files.

where it is being added :

```
package tabs.ibettergetagoodgradeforthisorillbepissed.sciencefair.beta.mmmeds.com.mmmedstabbeta;

/**
 * Created by WindowsSucks on 10/29/2014.
 */

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Locale;

public class AddMedFragment extends Fragment {

    private CharSequence mTitle;
    final static int RQS_1 = 1;



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_med_layout, container,false);

        final TextView medOut = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.medName);
        final TextView doseOut = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.dosageout);
        final TextView timeOut = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.timeOut);
        final TextView dayout = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.daystxt);
        final EditText med_dose = (EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.med_dose);



        med_dose.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                doseOut.setText(med_dose.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        final Button setTimePickerButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.timePickerButton);
        setTimePickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                TimePickerDialog dialog = new TimePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                                if(selectedHour > 12){
                                    selectedHour-= 12;
                                }

                                selectedMinute = timePicker.getCurrentMinute();
                                if(selectedMinute < 10){
                                    //selectedMinute = String.valueOf(selectedMinute);
                                    timeOut.setText(selectedHour + ":" +"0"+ selectedMinute);
                                }else{
                                    timeOut.setText(selectedHour + ":" + selectedMinute);
                                }



                            }
                        },hour,minute,false);

                dialog.setTitle("Select Time");
                dialog.show();

            }
        });

        final TextView medEntry = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.med_name);
        medEntry.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i2, int i3) {
                medOut.setText(medEntry.getText());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

            }
        });

        final Button dayPicker = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.dayPicker);
        dayPicker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final CharSequence[] items = {"Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"};
                // arraylist to keep the selected items
                final ArrayList selectedItems=new ArrayList();

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                builder.setTitle("Select Days To Take");
                builder.setMultiChoiceItems(items, null,
                        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected,
                                                boolean isChecked) {
                                if (isChecked) {
                                    // If the user checked the item, add it to the selected items
                                    selectedItems.add(indexSelected);
                                } else if (selectedItems.contains(indexSelected)) {
                                    // Else, if the item is already in the array, remove it
                                    selectedItems.remove(Integer.valueOf(indexSelected));
                                }
                            }
                        })
                        // Set the action buttons
                        .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {







                                //  Your code when user clicked on OK
                                //  You can write the code  to save the selected item here
                                String itemsChecked = selectedItems.toString();
                                String days = "";
                                if (itemsChecked.contains("0")) {
                                    days = days + " Sunday";
                                }
                                if (itemsChecked.contains("1")) {
                                    days = days + " Monday";
                                }
                                if (itemsChecked.contains("2")) {
                                    days = days + " Tuesday";
                                }
                                if (itemsChecked.contains("3")) {
                                    days = days + " Wednesday";
                                }
                                if (itemsChecked.contains("4")) {
                                    days = days + " Thursday";
                                }
                                if (itemsChecked.contains("5")) {
                                    days = days + " Friday";
                                }
                                if (itemsChecked.contains("6")) {
                                    days = days + " Saturday";
                                }



                                dayout.setText(days);
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                //  Your code when user clicked on Cancel

                            }
                        });

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();//AlertDialog dialog; create like this outside onClick
                dialog.show();
            }
        });


        String SDRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        final File output = new File (SDRoot,"output.txt");

        if(!output.exists()){
            try {
                output.createNewFile();
                Context context = getActivity();
                CharSequence text = "Output File Created!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                Toast fileCreated = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                fileCreated.show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Context context = getActivity();
                CharSequence text = "Output File Not Created!";
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

                Toast fileNotCreated = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
                fileNotCreated.show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }


        Button addbutton = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.addMeds);

        addbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Medication Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String outputLine = medOut.getText() + " "+ doseOut.getText() +" "+ dayout.getText() +":" + " "+ ":" + timeOut.getText() + "\n";

                try {
                    FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(output, true);
                    OutputStreamWriter myOutputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
                    myOutputStreamWriter.append(outputLine);
                    myOutputStreamWriter.flush();
                    myOutputStreamWriter.close();


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                ListView list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewMedsTxt);
                ((BaseAdapter)list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

And where it is being viewed:

```
package tabs.ibettergetagoodgradeforthisorillbepissed.sciencefair.beta.mmmeds.com.mmmedstabbeta;

/**
 * Created by WindowsSucks on 10/29/2014.
 */
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.SparseBooleanArray;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ViewMedFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_med_layout, container,false);
        getActivity().setTitle("View Medications");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        final ListView lv = (ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.viewMedsTxt);


        String SDRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
        final File output = new File(SDRoot,"output.txt");
        //Get the text file

        //Read text from file


        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        lv.setItemsCanFocus(true);


        final List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner reader = null;
        try {
            reader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(output), "UTF-8");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (reader != null) {
            if(!reader.hasNextLine()){
                lines.add("You have no medications, add some from the start screen!");
            }
        }
        if (reader != null) {
            while(reader.hasNextLine())
                lines.add(reader.nextLine());
        }


        if (reader != null) {
            reader.close();
        }

        final ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                lines );


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                for (int j = 0; j < parent.getChildCount(); j++)
                    parent.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

                // change the background color of the selected element
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
            }
        });

        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        Button delete = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.deleteMed);
        delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                /** Getting the checked items from the listview */
                SparseBooleanArray checkedItemPositions = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
                int itemCount = lv.getCount();

                for(int i=itemCount-1; i >= 0; i--){
                    if(checkedItemPositions.get(i)){
                        arrayAdapter.remove(lines.get(i));
                        try {
                            removeLine(output,i);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
                checkedItemPositions.clear();
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getString(R.string.medDeleted), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });




        return rootView;
    }

    public void removeLine(final File file, final int lineIndex) throws IOException{
        final List<String> lines = new LinkedList<>();
        final Scanner reader = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file), "UTF-8");
        while(reader.hasNextLine())
            lines.add(reader.nextLine());
        reader.close();
        if(lineIndex >= 0 && lineIndex <= lines.size() - 1)
            lines.remove(lineIndex);
        final BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, false));
        for(final String line : lines)
            writer.write(line + "\n");
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        ListView list = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.viewMedsTxt);
        ((BaseAdapter)list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Much thanks!

EDIT:

FragmentPageAdapter:

```
    package tabs.ibettergetagoodgradeforthisorillbepissed.sciencefair.beta.mmmeds.com.mmmedstabbeta;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:
                return new AddMedFragment(medView);
            case 1:

                return new ViewMedFragment();
            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why dont just create a listener interface called MedUpdateListener with a function updateMed().

```
 public interface MedUpdateListener {
     public void updateMed();
 }
```

let the ViewMedFrament be a MedUpdateListener and implement updateMed() so it re-reads your data.

```
 public class ViewMedFramgent extends Fragment implements MedUpdateListener{

 ...
 @Override
 public void updateMed(){
       do some update stuff for your list
 }

 }
```

Add a construtor to your AddMedFragment which accepts a MEdUpdateListener as parameter:

```
 public class AddMedFragment extends Framgment{

      private MedUpdateListener onUpdateListener;

      public AddMedFragment(MedUpdateListener onUpdateListener){
          this.onUpdateListener = onUpdateListener;
      }
 }
```

and whenever you add something:

```
 this.onUpdateLisener.updateMed();
```

when creating your Fragments:

```
 public class FragmentPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

     private Fragment[] frags = new Fragment[2];

     public FragmentPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
         super(fm);
         frags[0] = new ViewMedFragment();
         frags[1] = new AddMedFragment(frags[0]);
     }
     @Override
     public Fragment getItem(int pos) {
         return frags[pos];
     }
     @Override
     public int getCount() {
         return frags.length();
     }
 }
```

call onUpdateListener.updateMed() in your addButton

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you're saying

Comment: Where does the medView come from when adding the fragment? and where in the code would i implement this.onUpdateListener.updateMed()

And what code exactly would need to be used in the updateMed method..?

Added some code to show how im adding my fragments

Comment: Im getting "Cannot resolve symbol" on "onUpdateListener" when adding the "onUpdateListener.updatemed"

Comment: you need a private MedUpdateListener onUpdateListener in AddMedFragment of course. Edited my answer